# Flow: Enforce types on know fields only

Tags: flowtype

I there a Flow notation that would allow to define object type / interface that validates types of knows properties and unknown properties are not type-checked (are assumed of type `any`)?

```js
const a: {x: number} = { x: 0 }
a.x = 'foo' // desirable error - x is define as number
a.y = 'bar' // undesirable error
```

[Example in Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzAEMAuMAbwA8zsBXAWwCMBTAJwF8wBeCsasAAxh2qIgDpK3MAHIocONLDBgYACbNcAS1ZFGMZmDas4rMAFo+YTbjXMom7AaI26TNqLEBPKdMZFWispgtNjqWjp6BkYmqEA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define indexer property alongside with known properties:

```
const a: {x: number, [key:string]: any } = { x: 0 }
```

Or even shorter:

```
const a: {x: number, [string]: any } = { x: 0 }
```

More info [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps)